# Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'stopImmediatePropagation'

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

> Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'stopImmediatePropagation'

[image: jquery error]

Here is complete code which I get from 9lessons website.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".delete").live('click',function()
    {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var b=$(this).parent().parent();
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;
        if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!"))
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete_ajax.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(e)
                {
                    b.hide();
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                }
            });
        return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Error is pointing to `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`

How can I resolve this error? Thanks!

Comment: `e` in your code is Ajax response, not an event object.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  Ajax requests don't have an event whose propagation you would want to stop

Comment: Always first step is to check the jQuery docs. See `success` for `$.ajax` to know what parameters it accepts. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: If this is the 9lessons website's code, you need to stop learning from it

Answer (score 3):

The first variable passed to the success function should be a data object, not an event.  It seems like you want to grab the click event and cancel that since you're handling it.  So at the top, use this:

```
$(".delete").live('click',function(event)
{
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    ...everything else...
});
```

And remove the original e.stopImmediatePropagation();

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the event object in your clickhandler:

```
 $(".delete").live('click',function(e)
```

Comment: The line is in the `success` callback function

Answer (score -1):

This should do it...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".delete").live('click',function(evt)
{
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var b=$(this).parent().parent();
var dataString = 'id='+ id;
if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!"))
{
    $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "delete_ajax.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
async: false,
success: function(e)
{
b.hide();
evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
           });
    return false;
}
});
```

Note the `async: false;`, this will make your code execution wait for the Ajax to complete and will stop the click event. You cannot stop an event from a asynchronous success handler.